# Sublime Text 3 delete my php code when I save it

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminHomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return view('AdminHome')->withPages(Page::all());
    }
}
```

---

when i press ctrL+s to save it ,then some code is deleted . I don't know why ,can you give me a solution ?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminHomeController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        return view('AdminHome')->withPages(Page::all());
    }
}
```

the code become like this .

I installed packages for my sublime text 3 ,in the follow picture . I think it's caused by sublimeLinter , but I don't kow how to fix it , my user settings as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygb65.png)

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.15,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "load/save",
        "linters": {
            "php": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            },
            "phplint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": [
                "D:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.0.4"
            ]
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "javascript (babel)": "javascript",
            "magicpython": "python",
            "php": "html",
            "python django": "python",
            "pythonimproved": "python"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

---

This is the first time I ask question on this website ,and I am from China , my English is not very good .

Comment: No code is deleted it looks like. It just formats it differently. `{` aren't on their own line after you've saved it. Have you got a plugin that changes the PHP's format on save? -- On second look, it looks like a plugin is doing this, but what one, I can't tell.

Comment: use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;   these two lines is deleted .

Comment: http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/lint_modes.html#load-save 

Looks like it lints of file save.

Comment: yes , just look like .this question let me go insane . thank you ,you are the first one to answer this question . and i fell your passion from the other side of the world .

Comment: I think the Rquest` use is deleted as it's unused. try to edit the linter settings  then under `jslint_options` try to edit/add `"unparam": true,`

Comment: thank you ,but i don't know what you mean <code> settings then under jslint_options try to edit/add "unparam": true,</code> can you write it more frankly ?

Comment: and one more question ,when i make comment here , how to formate the content like yours ? grey background .

Comment: use two of ` and put your code inside. it's `markdown` styled

Comment: thank  you ,it works . we use markdown style too ,but the format is use six ` , and the code write between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your issue is reported before from `phpfmt` users. under package `settings-> phpfmt -> setting - User` then add `"passes": ["OnlyOrderUseClauses"]`. have a look on [this issue](https://github.com/nanch/phpfmt_stable/issues/14)

**update**: the working format is `"passes": "OnlyOrderUseClauses",` as @SHUIPING_YANG mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but couldn't figure out exactly why Sublime always deleting my PHP use statements; Moreover, while trying to troubleshoot the issue, I realized that my Sublime packages differed from the ones you had installed. Expect for one,  that was **SublimeCodeIntel**. I removed it, and upon pressing Ctrl + S, Sublime no longer removed the use statements.